# Microsoft Graph Teams Guest Invitation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to develop an app in Teams to help team owners invite external guests to their teams. The app uses graph api /invitations call in the backend to get the job done. We are restricting users who can invite guests by assigning them the User.Invite.All api permission in Azure portal under AD App registration blade. What we found was that even users who have not been assigned this permission are able to invite guests. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you gave the *delegated permission* User.Invite.All to the app, and the user is able to invite a user, then the user already had rights to invite users.
They would be able to go to e.g. portal.azure.com, and invite users from there as well in that case.

If you gave the *app permission* User.Invite.All to the app, then *any user* using the app can invite users, since the app itself has the permission and the user info is not even present in the access token.

Comment: My problem is that a person without the User.Invite.All is also able to invite guests which should not be entertained

Comment: A user cannot be assigned User.Invite.All. An app is given this permission, and a user can consent to the app to do it on their behalf. Like I said, if this was the delegated permission and the user can invite a user, then the user already has the permission.

Comment: If it's the app permission, then any user would have the permission by extension.

Comment: Agreed, if the app does have delegated User.Invite.All permission things should work. But the invitation call works even if the app doesn't have those permissions, that's my problem

Comment: Did you perhaps add the permission, consent to it and then remove the permission requirement? In that case the app would still have the permission, removing a required permission doesn't remove already given permissions.

Comment: I finally got a solution for this issue. There is something called a Guest Inviter Role in AAD which was the key. If we add the user here, the user will be able to send invites, else not. Thanks for you help junnas

Comment: Yup, that role gives users the ability to invite if they otherwise couldn't.